# Вопрос о правильности запятой

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Читал статью на Грамоте про [*так*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA&all=x) и нашёл там следующее:

> Подчёркивает наличие у лица, предмета и т. п. подлинных свойств, присущих данному роду лиц, предметов. *Женщина, так женщина! Вот это просьба, так просьба!*

Меня удивили запятые в примерах. Разве они там нужны?

Answer (score 2):

> *Держались они всегда стайкой: петь так петь, играть так играть* (Гайдар, Военная тайна).

> *Что поделаешь ― играть, так играть надо по совести, а то засмеют и из
> кона вон* (Миловский, Хрустальное яблоко).

> «Вот это пир так пир!» ― радостно восклицал изголодавшийся на тюремной
> пайке Юлик (Воронель, Без прикрас).

> *Коли спорить, так уж смело, Коль карать, так уж за дело, Коль
> простить, так всей душой, Коли пир ― так пир горой!* (Лурье,
> Дневник).

Примеры эти дают подсказку, в каком случае запятая необходима: это там, где устойчивая форма с ТАК как частицей деформируется, прирастая иными членами, меняющими смысл словосочетания. К таким случаям относится и урезанное, приведённое Грамотой (по статье из словаря С. Кузнецова), восклицание. Полная цитата выглядит иначе:

«В. Я. Шишков. Угрюм-река. Ч. 1-4 (1928-1933)

Илюха повеселел: сам большой ― сам маленький в лавке, хозяин пьет, хозяйка, хоть и забирает помаленьку все бразды, но женщина, так женщина и есть.»

Comment: Я бы даже в полной не стал ставить. Может, лучше так написать: "Примеры эти дают подсказку, в каком случае запятая необходима: это там, где устойчивая форма с ТАК как частицей деформируется..."? Чтобы понятно было, что это уже ответ на вопрос, какой же это случай, а не просто пояснение предыдущего придаточного.

Comment: Да, так определённее, т.е. понятнее.

Comment: Поставил плюсик, но жду ещё ответов. Всё-таки есть сомнение в запятой даже в полном варианте, и мне кажется, нельзя вырезать кусочек и оставлять ту же пунктуацию. Надо смотреть, надо ли её изменить и как, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Это не варианты. Есть конструкция устойчивая и конечная с видом на инаковость (исключительность) понятия. В ней ТАК — частица:*вот это добряк так добряк*. А есть — с союзом ТАК: *шляться ночью, так ночью темно*.

Comment: Понял теперь смысл с союзом в полной фразе и убедился, что с таким смыслом запятая нужна. Но всё равно, если вырезать "женщина так женщина" и оставить запятую, получается как-то странно...